# How to use static library(.a file) instead of a group of object files(.o) to create a shared library

Tags: c++, g++, linker-errors

I have a shared library and I use it to create an executable binary. I can only control the build process of the library and the executable binary and not the source files involved. As expected, the source files in executable binary refer to a lot of functions from the library.

Currently the shared library is built using the objectfiles(.o) directly.

```
g++ -shared ${OBJECT_FILES} -o ${SHARED_LIBRARY}
```

I want to publish the object files too by grouping them in a static library (.a file or achive).

To save on space, I delete all the .o files on creation of the archive file. So now, the build command is

```
g++ -shared ${ACRCHIVE_FILE} -o ${SHARED_LIBRARY}
```

The library builds fine.
But when I try to build the executable binary by linking to this shared library, the symbols refereed to by the binary are not defined and it fails to link. (undefined reference to `Context::Get()`)

By my understanding it should not matter if we create the shared library using .o files directly or an archive consisting of all the .o files, but evidently either it is not possible or I may be missing something.

Comment: Mebbe try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685617/missing-symbols-from-static-library-in-linked-executable

Comment: did you try building with g++ -shared -Wl,--no-undefined ${OBJECT_FILES} -o ${SHARED_LIBRARY} ?  Also by adding -Wl,-soname,<your shared obj.so.<version>> ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shared libraries `libfoo.so` should contain [PIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code) code and static libraries `libfoo.a`  contain ordinary non PIC code. So you cannot create a shared library from a static one.

<sup>Shared libraries want *Position Independent Code* because their segment(s) is [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)-ed at nearly arbitrary and variable addresses - without `MAP_FIXED` ... See also [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization).</sup>

You could in principle build a static library from PIC object files, but nobody does that in practice.

You might (if you really insist) make an [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) shared object made of non-PIC code, but the result would have very bad performance; the dynamic linker would have a lot of [relocations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_%28computing%29), so most segments would be unshared and the dynamic linking would be very slow.

To compile `foo.cc`  for a shared library into a PIC object file `foo.pic.o` :

```
g++ -Wall -c -O foo.cc  -fPIC -o foo.pic.o
```

To compile it for a static library int an ordinary non-PIC object file `foo.o` :

```
g++ -Wall -c -O foo.cc -o foo.o
```

To make a shared library of `foo.pic.o` and `bar.pic.o`  into `libfoobar.so`  linking in some `libdep.so`  shared library:

```
g++ -shared foo.pic.o bar.pic.o -ldep -o libfoobar.so
```

<sup>You often want to add more linking options when making a shared library like above, e.g. `-Wl,-rpath,`...  or `-Wl,-soname,`....</sup>

BTW, it is not possible to link an archive `libfoobar.a`  (even if it is made of PIC files) into a `libfoobar.so`  because no name is undefined and requires linking some object files from `libfoobar.a` (maybe you could try to undefine some symbol `symb` with `-u symb` but I don't recommend doing that).

To make a static library of `foo.o`  and `bar.o`  into `libfoobar.a` :

```
ar cv libfoobar.a foo.o bar.o
```

Notice that [ranlib](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/ranlib.html) (creating an index of the archive) is no more necessary since GNU `ar`  does its job.

Read also [ld.so(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html), [ldd(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html), [ld(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html), [ar(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ar.1.html), [objdump(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/objdump.1.html), [readelf(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/readelf.1.html), [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) (often, you need to link the main program with `-rdynamic` if it loads `dlopen`-ed plugins at runtime, to enable the plugin to find some symbols in the main program).

NB: I would just build a shared library and not care about static linking at all. Notice that on some systems, PIC has a slight cost (slightly bigger and/or slower code). AFAIK, PIC overhead is less costly on x86-64 than on 32 bits Linux x86 code. On some architectures and ABIs PIC may have negligible overhead (or perhaps even be more efficient than non position independent code).

References: [*Drepper's paper:* How to Write Shared Libraries](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) & [*Levine's book:* Linkers and Loaders](http://www.iecc.com/linker) & [Program Library HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/)

Comment: I always thought that .a is nothing more than an archive of .o files, no different in principle from .tar.gz or .zip or even a directory. Was I wrong?

Comment: The `ar`  command also does what `ranlib`  used to do: make some index.

Comment: So how is .a library related to PIC?

Comment: It (a static `libxxx.a` library) is unrelated to PIC, it contains non PIC objects

Comment: So if the .o that went into .a were compiled with -fPIC, then we should be ok?

Comment: What "should be ok" ?

Comment: "should be OK" = We could unpack .a and use the .o's to create a shared library

Comment: Yes but if everything works if the .o files compiled with -fPIC used for building libfoo.so , whats wrong in providing them(the same object files) packed into an archive . I am unable to understand why would the symbols be undefined in the library.
Please excuse me if I am missing something here.